# What are SCADA Boxes?

Tags: control-engineering, industrial-engineering

I've seen the terms "SCADA boxes", "SCADA out-of-the-box", "SCADA turnkey systems" used in various articles but without a definition. I'd like to know whether the terms are synonymous and if not what is the "generally accepted" concept of a "SCADA box"?

Comment: A box alone is not a turnkey system.

Comment: Have you googled « scada » to at least find out what you may be talking about?

Comment: @SolarMike There is a lot of information on SCADA. Most descriptions describe the HMI, RTU/PLC and Supervisory System. However, they do not mention "SCADA box". It appears that it is an informal term used by field technicians to refer to the RTU/PLC devices that they install in the field. I was just looking for confirmation that my guess was correct.

Comment: I know what scada means - have spent enough time analysing data recorded by such systems... I wanted to know what you had checked... but it was not just scada box you said you did not understand,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plant I used to work at had a Supervisory Control And Data Acquisition (SCADA).  They had all kinds of transducers measuring everything in sight and we could sit in the control room and check on things all over the plant.

(*warstory*)
One night (when I should have been working) I was poking around and noticed the temperature of the Feedwater pump A bearing was high and just then, the call came in from the field that the Feedwater pump B was burning up and we needed to take it down.

I showed the high temp on the A pump to the operator on duty and he checked with the field operator who confirmed it was Feedwater pump B so he cut Feedwater B.  The operator in the field immediately called back with "A, the A pump, not the B pump."  The good news was we were able to bring B back up without too much delay and the plant had no difficulty.
(*end warstory*)

At this point, I have no recollection of being able to actually control anything with the SCADA system, such as turn on equipment, it was all for data logging.  How did that differ from the Plant Monitoring System (PMS)?  Again, I don't recall except to say that it allow monitoring all kinds of things that were not available to the PMS.

The SCADA system had these Remote Terminal Units (RTUs) out in the field that would interface with the transducers and send the data back to the system that was used for display.

I am suspicious of anybody that says they have a turn-key SCADA system.  I expect they will sell you their off-the-shelf display software and the RTUs (or whatever their modern equivalents are) and a then charge you for the (possibly huge amount of) time spent on configuration.  I would rather sign up to buy an "off-the-shelf" SCADA than try to cook something up in-house but it is hardly turn-key.

*But that is not your question.*

From what I can find on the web, it appears the SCADA-boxes you refer to are the modern equivalent of RTUs.  They receive the data from the transducers, package it up and send it back to the main data logging and display system via some sort of network.  The out-of-the-box and turnkey systems are the same thing.  You buy display and data logging software from the vendor and either play hell configuring it yourself or pay them big bucks to do the configuration for you.